# Allow both http and https with Traefik on Docker

Tags: docker, http, ssl, https, traefik

I am using `Traefik` in my VPS to route the traffic to my websites, after hours of messing around with it I finally managed to get it working with `https` using Le's Encrypt.

Now, one thing that I need to do is be able to also access my website via plain `http` as this is a hobby project for older browsers and the only reason I added `tls` is because Firefox doesn't like my website without it.

The problem is that, with my current configuration, I can access my website via `https` normally but when I try it with plain `http` I get a `404` error.

Here's what my config on `docker-compose` looks like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.5"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.teeresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.teeresolver.acme.email=me@gmail.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.teeresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      - mywebsite
  # [...]
  mywebsite:
    image: my-web-site/site
    build:
      context: ~/mywebsite-runner/_work/my-web-site-php/my-web-site-php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./tee-downloads:/var/www/build/downloads
      - ./tee-contents:/var/www/build/contents
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8001:80"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.themywebsite.rule=Host(`mywebsite.com`, `www.mywebsite.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.themywebsite.entrypoints=websecure,web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.themywebsite.tls.certresolver=teeresolver"
    networks:
      - mywebsite

networks:
  mywebsite:
```

I have been searching for a solution for hours but the only things I can find on google are configs to redirect `http` to `https`, which I can't do.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: have you tried accessing the traefik dashboard ?

Comment: Not yet. I need to setup a subdomain and I haven't taken the time to do that yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In traefik , each `router` defines a set of policies to apply depending of rules and entrypoints.

If you want 2 policies, one for http and one for https, you need to define 2 traefik `routers` :

```yaml
  mywebsite:
    ...
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.themywebsite.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.themywebsite.tls.certresolver=teeresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.themywebsite.rule=Host(`mywebsite.com`, `www.mywebsite.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.httpwebsite.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.httpwebsite.rule=Host(`mywebsite.com`, `www.mywebsite.com`)"
```

- One called `themywebsite`
- Another one called `httpwebsite`

As a result, you do not use a certresolver for `httpwebsite` router.

Comment: No problem, I've been struggling with it too.

Comment: ugh I was having so much trouble with this, then seeing your answer it was so simple. Thanks